# RewriteRule changes physical paths for files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say the domain for my website is [http://mywebsite.com][1] and that opens the index.php. That script gets the $page,$section,$language variables from the url. So [http://mywebsite.com/index.php?lang=en&section=home&page=sitemap][2] opens the sitemap page in English which belongs to the "home" section. And I want that same url to be rewritten to [http://mywebsite.com/home/sitemap_en.html][3]. To achieve this, already I've put the following in the .htaccess:
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .+\/.+
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/(.+)_(mk|en|al)\.html$ index.php?lang=$3&section=$1&page=$2 [L]`
But there is a huge problem now. When I visit some url like that, the files are not found because the file style.css is in the root folder and not in [http://mywebsite.com/home/style.css][4] , and there the server is searching for it. "home" is not real folder and it doesn't exists, it's only a section. The same goes for all the jpg, png, js, gif etc. How can I redirect the pages the way I like, and the files to be found with the real paths?

p.s. Some section like [http://mywebsite.com/index.php?lang=en&section=contact][5] don't have pages at all. They should be reached like so: [http://mywebsite.com/contact_en.html][6]
I have this for them, after the previous rule: RewriteRule ^(.+)_(mk|en|al).html$ index.php?lang=$2&section=$1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [base](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) tag in your header so that all relative paths are off of a specific href so:

```
<head>
    <base href="http://mywebsite.com/" />
</head>
```

would cause **all relative** (not just css) URL's to be loaded off your root directory

OR

as stated by others just make your paths absolute by putting a leading "/" at the front:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mycss.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer , I didn't even knew that base tag existed at all. Now I don't have to edit all the hrefs, which are a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try and make the references to css and js files etc relative to the top level directory (the home directory) by prefixing with a slash? ie if you keep them in a directory called styles in the sites home directory:

```
<link rel=StyleSheet href="/styles/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Hey I can not believe how obvious this was :) all my src and href were like href="images/design/favicon.ico" and when I put slash in front like href="/images/design/favicon.ico" they loaded just fine, DUH :) Thank a lot bro. I think that would solve all my problems, hope new won't occur.